# Can my phone go silent whenever I'm asleep?

Tags: automation, silent-mode

Is there a setting, app, or combination of apps that can turn my phone silent whenever I'm asleep?  Without me needing to schedule or toggle anything?

So if I'm up late or early, I still hear a text arrive, but if I nap midday it's silent, without me needing to remember to turn some settings on or off?  Maybe some sleep app can do this?  Or maybe IFTTT, Tasker, MacroDroid, or some other, can deduce whether I'm asleep, from Fitbit, or some other sleep app?

My phone has Android 12 but is a tad dated (Pixel 3 XL), so a solution that doesn't suck lots of battery would be preferable.

Comment: I guess the biggest problem is how to determine whether you're really asleep or just idling. Google has [Sleep API](https://developers.google.com/location-context/sleep) that may determine based on certain conditions, while [Tasker](https://www.xda-developers.com/tasker-beta-custom-sleep-tracker-android) has integrated it. However, I haven't tested how it works in general.

Comment: You should also state where the phone is located if you are sleeping/napping (pants pocket, shirt pocket, external bag/table), how you are sleeping (lying down on bed/couch, sitting in chair, head down on tablet) and what other devices you have on your person (Fitbit, Android watch, etc.) which can signal to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Pixel device with factory ROM/updates, you have a variety of options for alerting behavior.

From: https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6111295?hl=en

> **Limit interruptions with Do Not Disturb on Pixel phone**
>
> Quickly turn interruptions off or back on
> Here are some ways to silence your phone:
>
> - All Pixel phones: From the top of your screen, swipe down. Then tap Do Not Disturb.
> - All Pixel phones (Pixel 2-4): To silence incoming calls, squeeze your phone. Learn how to use Active Edge.
> - Pixel 2 & later: Place your phone face down on a flat surface. Learn how to use Flip to Shhh.
> - From another device: If you have a Smart Display or speaker, you can ask it to silence your phone. Learn how to limit interruptions with the Google Assistant.

See link for details.

Also be aware that Google's [Digital Wellbeing feature](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/9137850) has a [Bedtime mode](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/9137850#zippy=%2Chow-to-set-a-bedtime-routine) but that is based on a schedule or device charging with a preset time window.

Comment: the point of the question is so the phone can just do it without me needing to remember to do it.  i'll edit it to make that point more clearly.